# Why does Elle remember a home in Los Angeles?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-black-lotus

In the *Blade Runner: Black Lotus* episode *City of Angels*, Elle goes to Los Angeles guided by a faint memory of a building with an angel painted on the wall as "home".

In the later episode *the Doll Hunt*, she learns she was one of multiple replicants created specifically for humans to hunt and kill for sport.

So why does she have memories of a home in LA?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the memory implant technology that was developed to give replicants a more natural emotional affect so humans could identify with them more and the replicants would be less likely to have episodes that would be termed psychotic in humans. Replicants are biomechanical, so they mimic humans in a lot of ways, and humans need memories to have emotions that both allow them to function well and overseers to manipulate them with standardized cues and tricks, as well as make the replicants not come off as creepy psychos when interacting with humans.

This means they put memories of a stitched-together past into their heads. However, in her case, it seems she also has some real experiences that were suppressed, like with a memory block. In the original movie, Deckard tells Rachel her childhood memories are scavenged from the engrams of Tyrell's daughters and edited together. So Elle has the same basic implantation of memories, scavenged from other real sources, edited together, and implanted.

At least this is what I garner from watching the movies and the series.

Answer (score 0):

It's because

> Elle was first awakened in the Wallace Corporation corporate headquarters in LA. We see Water Lily (another black lotus) getting her tattoo in the same location. Apparently the memories were intentionally distorted so she would have dig to figure out the man in the memory is Niander Wallace Jr.

It's likely the memory of the angel was implanted to help her find Joseph